# Avoid smartcards using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, smartcard

When I run unit tests with puppeteer, my smartcard (observed with a YubiKey or Nitrokey) gets accessed; you can see the light blink. I am using that smart card in my host system, but do not want to access it from puppeteer.

This slows down the tests, and is not desirable in general; the tests should certainly not use my smartcard.

How can I prevent puppeteer/chromium from accessing smartcards? I am fine with a Linux-only solution.

Comment: What's inside the tests? What if it's testing a smartcard feature?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher These are tests that connect to the websites I'm developing. I know that none of the tests use smartcards.

Comment: Sounds like you are retrieving a certificate from a smart card for authentication use, possibly for the OS or for setting up a TLS socket. Could it be you've installed additional plugins?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, I hope that was clear. I extended the question. But plugins in puppeteer? No, I can reproduce the behavior in a brand-new puppeteer installation.

Comment: With Windows there is a service for certificate propagation. Maybe there is something similar in your Linux config? This is probably better asked at Superuser or a Linux Q/A site, rather than SO.